# killing unknown launch daemon

Tags: macos, daemon

I was debugging a launch daemon, and somehow created one I can neither kill nor even find an associated `Label`.  I know its running because it's appending to a "hello world" file every 10 seconds.  What are my options to debug this?  Is there a way to back out what process is running the shell script?

I've tried:

- `launchctl unload` all .plists I've edited that still exist
- `launchctl list | grep` for all Labels that I created (I think!!)
- restarted the system

I have tried all suggestions posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/121355/stop-a-runaway-launchd-process-on-os-x-leopard) and elsewhere.

Reference page [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/DesigningDaemons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW4-BBCBHBFB)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww this is debugging a launch daemon for a programming task.  Similar questions have been asked before...

Comment: How ironic you are finding similar questions and answers on other sites, like [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @jww I fail to see the irony; there is obvious overlap on some of the SE sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daemon behavior/visibility is tied to the owner.  For system daemons, the preferred syntax (as of 2017) is:

- any `.plist` file should be owned by root in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` or else it may not load correctly.
- daemons started (as root) with `sudo launchctl load my_daemon.plist` will only with the command `sudo launchctl list`; likewise
- daemons started (as user) with `launchctl load my_daemon.plist` will only with the command `sudo launchctl list`

If at any time in the past a `load` has been invoked with the `-w` flag the daemon will be persistently loaded, even after reboot, and require `-w` to unload it:

- `sudo launchctl load -w my_daemon.plist` to load a daemon, and
- `sudo launchctl unload -w my_daemon.plist`.

In the case of the question, the daemon was likely launched with some combination of `sudo` and/or `-w` and then queried/"stopped" without.